# CTE Query throws Recursion Exhausted error

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

The following CTE Query throws "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion."

```
WITH MyCTE
AS (
SELECT o.organizationid,
        organization AS organization 
FROM organization o
    INNER JOIN store s ON s.organizationid = o.organizationid
UNION ALL
SELECT store.storeid,
            CAST(storeNAme AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS storeNAme 
FROM store
    INNER JOIN MyCTE ON store.organizationid = MyCTE.organizationid)

    SELECT DISTINCT
            Organization
    FROM MyCTE
```

when executing the subquery before and after the union all, the followig result is gained.

Anchor query:-
    SELECT o.organizationid,
            organization AS organization 
    FROM organization o
        INNER JOIN store s ON s.organizationid = o.organizationid
Result:-

```
organizationid    |organization
--------------------------------
3                 | Org1
```

query after union all:-

SELECT store.storeid,
                    CAST(storeNAme AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS storeNAme 
            FROM store

Result:-

```
StoreId           |StoreName
--------------------------------
3                 | Warehouse1
```

May I know the reason why ?

Answer (score 3):

Specify the maxrecursion option at the end of the query:

```
...
from MyCTE
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

That allows you to specify how often the CTE can recurse before generating an error. Maxrecursion 0 allows infinite recursion.

Comment: 1+ from me and some addition to answer: By default maximum recursion level supported by CTE is 100. But CTE provides an option to change it by means of the MAXRECURSION hint. MAXRECURSION hint value can be between 0 to 32,767. Specifying it’s value as 0 means no limit.

Comment: @Raj   I want to know why the Query goes into maximum recursion when individual queries only Return one row as the result

Answer (score 1):

I think we can try this to increase the max recursion depth :

SET GLOBAL cte_max_recursion_depth=10000;

According here, https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?100,681245,681245

Answer (score 0):

When you are running recursive query, you allow a query to call itself. It doesn't matter how many rows query returns, but how many times a query will call itself. Therefore there is a risk it might go into infinite loop while. SQL Server in order to prevent this situation from happening have a setting which will determine how many recursions are allowed. Default value for this setting is 100 - therefore you will get this message when your query exceeds 100 recursions (self calls).

You can override this setting by adding `OPTION (MAXRECURSION nn)` at the end of query. When **nn** is new maximum.

You can also remove protection completely by setting this value to 0 - it will looks like this then: `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` however this is not recommended since when running it will keep consuming resources.

---

OP asked for suggestion how to avoid potential infinite loop, and create exit criteria for recursion.

As far as I can see you are trying to build data hierarchy. You might consider introducing additional column with hierarchy level and stop at some level (I choose 10 in example):

```
WITH MyCTE
     AS (
     SELECT o.organizationid,
            organization AS organization,
          1 lvl
     FROM organization o
          INNER JOIN store s ON s.organizationid = o.organizationid
     UNION ALL
     SELECT store.storeid,
            CAST(storeNAme AS NVARCHAR(50)) AS storeNAme,
          lvl+1
     FROM store
          INNER JOIN MyCTE ON store.organizationid = MyCTE.organizationid
     WHERE lvl<10
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    Organization
FROM MyCTE
```

Comment: ive given the result from the subquery .... its a single row being returned from both subqueries .... **why does** the query go into recursion is my question

Comment: Check my updated answer. It doesn't matter how many rows you'll get - what matters is how many it will call itself.

Comment: By the way, I would assume there is a good chance query might actually go into infinite loop (depends on your data) if you set MAXRECURSION to 0.

Comment: Even if I add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION nn)` query would still get same error , I need to know why theres an infinite recursion possiblity here

Comment: may I know what makes that data go into infinite recursion? :)

Comment: Imagine loop which looks like this: while(1) { .. } so this is how your query behaves (this is my assumption). You need exit criteria which will stop this loop at some point and since you do not have any, it will go into infinite loop.

Comment: could u suggest one in this case?